# I try to add entity model class data to my another list ,but after foreach Same rows insert in every row , MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, entity

> This is my Entity model class which was auto generated by Ado.net model

```
 public partial class SubModule
    {
        public int SubModuleId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ModuleId { get; set; }
        public string SubModuleName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Active { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsModules { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string path { get; set; }
        public string subform { get; set; }
    }


this is my another class

 public class ChildModules
    {
        public int ? SubModuleId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ModuleId { get; set; }
        public string SubModuleName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Active { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsModules { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string path { get; set; }
        public string subform { get; set; }

    }
```

> I want to copy Sub modules data to my Child modules class properties
>
> My code is

```
 List<SubModule> ChildModule = entity.SubModules.Where(x => x.IsModules == false).ToList();
            List<ChildModules> listchildmodules = new List<ChildModules>();
            ChildModules chmodule = new ChildModules();

            foreach (SubModule mod in ChildModule)
            {
                chmodule.SubModuleId = mod.SubModuleId;
                chmodule.ModuleId = mod.ModuleId;
                chmodule.SubModuleName = mod.SubModuleName;
                chmodule.Active = mod.Active;
                chmodule.IsModules = mod.IsModules;
                chmodule.url = mod.url;
                chmodule.path = mod.path;
                chmodule.subform = mod.subform;

                listchildmodules.Add(chmodule);
            }
```

> but in listchildmodules last row insert in every index.
>
> Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code always add the same object always. Because you always updating the values of same object and insert that into list.

Keep the below line of code inside foreach.

**ChildModules chmodule = new ChildModules();**

Your foreach should look like below

```
        foreach (SubModule mod in ChildModule)
        {
            ChildModules chmodule = new ChildModules();
            chmodule.SubModuleId = mod.SubModuleId;
            chmodule.ModuleId = mod.ModuleId;
            chmodule.SubModuleName = mod.SubModuleName;
            chmodule.Active = mod.Active;
            chmodule.IsModules = mod.IsModules;
            chmodule.url = mod.url;
            chmodule.path = mod.path;
            chmodule.subform = mod.subform;

            listchildmodules.Add(chmodule);
        }
```

Or you could declare **ChildModules chmodule;** outside foreach and initialize **chmodule = new ChildModules();** inside foreach loop.